# How to find a plaintext sibling in BeautifulSoup 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

For example:

```html
<p>I am in a paragraph element!</p>

I am plaintext!
```

How can I get the `I am plaintext!` text in BeautifulSoup 4 by calling `find("p")`?

I have already tried this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("...", "html.parser")

soup.find("p").findNextSibling()
# Returns None
```

Comment: Can you share an example with the surrounding elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `.find_next_sibling()` with parameter `text=True`:

```
txt = '''
<p>I am in a paragraph element!</p>

I am plaintext!'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('p').find_next_sibling(text=True))
```

Prints:

```
I am plaintext!
```